# What does the sentence "Please don't drop this from your radar" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning, sentence-meaning

What does the sentence "Please don't drop this from your radar" mean. I searched for this in Google I found some idiom named drop off the radar but still I need some clarity on this. I want to learn English please help me

Comment: This is a use of the idiom  'Drop off the radar' so if you found an explanation for that it should be clear, what didn't you understand?

Comment: I didn't understand what exactly to drop off the radar mean

Comment: What it means *exactly* depends on the context,  the first definition on Google is quite concise.

Comment: To drop off radar, means drop off your sight, in other words stop keeping it mind. If you drop something off your radar, you aren't making that something important enough for your attention. The phrase "Don't drop this off the radar" means please pay attention to this in your general life as you go along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is something that you shouldn't forget, but does not need immediate attention. It isn't happening at the moment, but don't forget about it.

Answer (score 1):

"Dropping off the radar" refers, in the literal sense, to an object, person or creature that is traveling across the range of a radar system. A radar operator would monitor its progress from when it was first detected to when it goes out of range, or "drops off" the radar's field of view.

As it passes through the field, the object reflects the radar signal back to the radar antenna only when it is pointed directly at the object. At that point, it appears as a blip on the radar screen. After the rotating antenna has come nearly full circle, the object is once again imaged and the operator notes the new location to track the movement, direction and speed of the object.

In the metaphorical sense, however, this phrase refers to an issue that does not require immediate attention or a task that cannot be completed immediately. One may be asked to periodically monitor the issue, but not necessarily do anything about it or spend much time on it. Then if by distraction or inattention one loses sight of the issue, the opportunity to act may have passed. In this sense, the lost opportunity is like the image of the object that dropped off the radar screen.